# Python find position of last digit in string

Tags: python

I have a string of characters with no specific pattern. I have to look for some specific words and then extract some information. 
Currently I am stuck at finding the position of the last number in a string.

So, for example if:

```
mystring="The total income from company xy was 12320 for the last year and 11932 in the previous year"
```

I want to find out the position of the last number in this string. 
So the result should be "2" in position "70".

Comment: Getting answers providing no code snippet to check. Lucky!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression, here's a quick attempt:

```
>>>mo = re.match('.+([0-9])[^0-9]*$', mystring)
>>>print mo.group(1), mo.start(1)
2 69
```

This is a 0-based position, of course.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generator expression to loop over the enumerate from trailing within a `next` function:

```
>>> next(i for i,j in list(enumerate(mystring,1))[::-1] if j.isdigit())
70
```

Or using regex :

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> m=re.search(r'(\d)[^\d]*$',mystring)
>>> m.start()+1
70
```

Answer (score 1):

Save all the digits from the string in an array and pop the last one out of it.

```
array = [int(s) for s in mystring.split() if s.isdigit()]
lastdigit = array.pop()
```

It is faster than a regex approach and looks more readable than it.

Comment: Agreed on the readability of this answer - could make it even simpler and perhaps even more readable: `lastdigit = max([int(s) for s in mystring.split() if s.isdigit()])`

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_last(s):
    temp = list(enumerate(s))
    temp.reverse()
    for pos, chr in temp:
        try:
            return(pos, int(chr))
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Comment: While this may provide an answer to the question, it helps to provide some commentary so others can learn "why" this code does what it does. Please see [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for ways to add more detail/context to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the string and get the first match with a simple regex:

```
s = mystring[::-1]
m = re.search('\d', s)
pos = len(s) - m.start(0)
```